# How to change instanly a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know that this might be a stupid question but it drives me crazy. I'm trying to change the innerHTML of a DOM element but it doesn't change until the end of the function's execution. For example:

```
function test(){
  let testEl = document.getElementById('testEl')
 
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  {
    testEl.innerHTML = 'Count: ' + i; 
    alert(i);
  }

}
```

Even if I have put an alert in the loop, the text of the element will not change until the end of the function's execution. How can the change be applied instantly (for example I mean during the loop)?

Comment: You need to make animation with timeouts

Comment: Because the thread is blocking.  In this particular case I don't see how it would make a difference though.  The code will complete 5 loops faster than the human eye could even recognize the 5 differences.  (If the display could even distinctly render all 5 of them that quickly.)

Comment: @David There is an alert() in every repetition which freeze the execution. So, the user will be able to see the change. The thing is that the DOM element doesn't change. If you add a console.log('Count: ' + i) you will be able to see the numbers in the console (one by one after the alert message)  but still not in the DOM element.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xsvn6VUTwQ

Comment: You need to learn a bit more about single and multi-threaded processing. JavaScript is a single threaded processing language. But, it's executed within a client that is multi-threaded (the browser). JavaScript may ask for an `alert` but it's the browser that asks the operating system to do that in a separate thread and since an alert is a "modal" dialog, it blocks all other browser execution, so you won't see the page update while the alert is present.

Comment: Actually the alert is just for the example. What I do is to change a DOM in the begining (put for example a "loading" text) then calling a php file to fetch some data and then change again the DOM to "Done". The only think I see is the 'Done' in the end even if the processing takes 4-5 secs. I assume it has to do with sync/asych, so your answers are helpful!

Comment: There's just no guarantee that the browser can or will update the UI in between alerts this way. Firefox does it, chrome doesn't. You can however code it so you can update an element in between alerts for all browsers.

Comment: That's because the process goes so fast, it's done almost immediately. Majed's answer below is the correct way to "slow things down" so that you can see the changes taking place.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't think so. I've put a timer running every 0.5 secs (after page loads). I have a button that starts the execution of the script. The timer freezes for a while when the script executes. I think it has to do with the opening of an XMLHttpRequest that I do. If I use console to log what I want it works perfectly but that doesn'y apply for the DOM element

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't think so, but you are mistaken. I've been doing and teaching this since JavaScript was invented. If your timer is freezing, it's because you aren't implementing it correctly. An XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous by default, so that wouldn't block your JavaScript code. As I said, you need to learn how asynchronous processing works in JavaScript, which is single-threaded. That single-thread always takes priority over any asynchronous code it may have spawned (like timers). So timers cannot be counted on to run exactly at the time specified.

Comment: I'm very happy you're teaching JS since 1995! XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous by default but that changes if you set async to false (that's what I've done). So, I have to set async to true and manage the script's continuation from the .onload function of the request. That's the whole thing.

Comment: Setting async to `false` defeats the entire purpose of an XHR and so you might as well just execute an inline function - that's the whole thing. You're not doing what you are attempting to do correctly and we're trying to tell you how to do it, but you seem to want to just be argumentative.

Comment: @ScottMarcus "That's because the process goes so fast, it's done almost immediately. Majed's answer below is the correct way to "slow things down" so that you can see the changes taking place". That was your answer and I reply "I don't think so" because it that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript runs in a single-threaded environment. This means that only one execution context can ever be running at any single point in time. Asynchronous code executes outside of the JavaScript runtime environment (in this case by the browser's native processing) and only when the JavaScript thread is idle can the results of an asynchronous request be executed (i.e. callbacks).

Below is an example that updates a DOM element approximately every second, creating a clock. However, if you click the button, it will ask the browser to render an `alert`, which is handled outside of the JavaScript runtime and is a blocking UI element, so the clock will stop. Once you clear the alert, you will see the time jump to be roughly current.

As you'll see, the asynchronous API call to `window.setInterval()` allows for the function to run repeatedly, every so often, and therefore not continuously. This replaces the need for a loop that runs in its entirety every time its accessed. Because of this, you can see updates to the webpage instead of the last value of your loop.

See the comments for more details:

```js
const clock = document.querySelector("span");

// setInterval is not JavaScript. It's a call to a browser
// API asking the JS runtime to run the supplied function every
// 900 milliseconds, but that's just a request. After 900 
// milliseconds, the browser will place the function on the
// JavaScript event queue and only when the JavaScript thread
// is idle will anything on the queue be executed. This is why
// the 900 milliseconds is not a guarantee - - it's just the 
// minimum amount of time you'll have to wait for the function
// to run, but it could be longer if what's already running
// on the JavaScript thread takes longer than 900 milliseconds
// to complete.
window.setInterval(function(){
  // Update the DOM
  clock.textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}, 900);

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // An alert is also not JavaScript, but another browser API that is executed
  // by the browser, not JavaScript. However, it is a blocking (modal) UI element.
  // The rest of the browser interface (including the web page) cannot update
  // while the alert is present. As soon as the alert is cleared, the UI will update.
  window.alert("I'm a UI blocking construct rendered by the browser, not JavaScript");
});
```

```html
<div>Current time is: <span></span></div>
<button>Click for alert</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can update the number every period of time using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```js
function test(){
  let testEl = document.getElementById('testEl');
  let i = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    testEl.innerHTML = `Count: ${i++}`;
    if(i === 5)
      clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000);
}

test();
```

```html
<p id="testEl"></p>
```

Comment: The Interval solution doesn't help my situation. On your first solution just put an alert in the loop to see what exactly I mean:

`
function test(){
  let testEl = document.getElementById('testEl')
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    testEl.innerHTML += `Count: ${i}<br>`;
    alert('PAUSE'); // testEL haven't changed and it will not until the end of the function 
  }
}

test();
`

Comment: @MyWherany the ``for-loop`` is fast and it's normal to see only the end result. This is why I suggested to append the content to show all the iterations, or use an interval to show the variable change slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it is by using `async` - `Promise` like this

```
async function test() {
    let testEl = document.getElementById('testEl')

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        testEl.innerHTML = 'Count: ' + i;

        await new Promise((resolve, _) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve("");
            }, 1000 /* your preferred delay here */);
        });
    }
}
```